# How can I setText for a JLabel so it prints multiple print statements from a void method?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I will give you a snippet of my code:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Flip");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Flips flip = new Flips();

        flipsLabel.setText(Arrays.toString(flip.hAndT));

        flip.tailsCount();
        tailsLabel.setText("Total Tails " + Integer.toString(flip.tCount));

        flip.headsCount();
        headsLabel.setText("Total Tails " + Integer.toString(flip.hCount));
    }
});
```

The above is all working because the `tCount` and `hCount` are variables so I can set them as text in the JLabels.

However, I have the following method that I want to print to a JLabel as well:

```
public static void headsCount() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Heads");
    System.out.println("=====");

    for (int i = 0; i < HandT.length; i++) {
        if (hAndT[i].equals("Head")) {
            System.out.println("index " + Integer.toString(i));
            hCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is multiple lines for the indices where heads falls in an array. I cannot print this void method by setting it as text for a button action because it is a primitive type.

Will I have to turn the method into a return type and return an array of some sort with this information so I can print it to a JLabel?

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most of your names are correct but not all of them. Be consistent!

Comment: @camickr I'm combining code from multiple people and am focused on functionality now. I'll move on to formatting last. Thank you for picking up on that, though!

Comment: Fixing the formatting can help you to find problems directly, or relax your mind enough to think about how to fix your problems.  Never save formatting for the end, especially if you want others to help you.

Comment: @GilberLeBlanc thank you. I ended up fixing the formatting before continuing anyway and it didn't give me much insight but it does look cleaner!

Comment: @seerocode, `I'll move on to formatting last.` - Do it right the first time and you spend less time fixing the code. Also, if you want to post code for people in the forum to read then the code should be properly formatted. Remember you are the person that wants help so your job is to make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: @camickr yes, I understand the importance.  I don't otherwise produce code with such formatting mistakes and I knew what they were and where they were in the code to fix it. As I said, I fixed the formatting and then continued working.

Comment: @seerocode, and all I said was to that that BEFORE you post your code in the forum. You still have not updated the code you posted in the forum so anybody reading this question will see incorrect code. So the point is do it properly in your original code and then when you copy/paste the code in the forum it will also be correct.

Comment: @camickr I know, I get you. I just wanted to make sure I was understood as well. The code isn't incorrect. It's working correctly or at least, to the point I need it to work but some variables are not written out properly as you said. I  will edit the code so the hAndT and count variables read correctly in case anyone else needs to understand it.  Thank you again for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will I have to turn the method into a return type

Yes, you would probably return a `String`.

Instead of using the System.out.println(), you might use a `StringBuilder` and keep appending the text to the `StringBuilder`.

Then you can simply use the `toString()` method of the `StringBuilder` to return the complete `String`.

> so I can print it to a JLabel?

I doubt you would use a JLabel, since a JLabel is not designed to display multiple lines of text. You might instead use a `JTextArea`.

If you want to use a JLabel then you could still use the StringBuilder to build HTML to display in the Label.

Comment: A text area is a better option. I'll work on the StringBuilder and test that out. Thank you!